# Convergence of the double series

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis

Let $\{a_i\}_{i\in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of positive real numbers, whose series converges i.e. $\sum\limits_{i\in \mathbb{N}}a_i = a < \infty.$ Does this imply the convergence of the double series $\sum\limits_{i,j \in \mathbb{N}}a_i a_j?$

If yes, how can this be proven? If not, what are some counterexamples?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

P.S. : A double series $\sum\limits_{i,j \in \mathbb{N}}a_i a_j$ converges to A, if for all $\epsilon > 0,$ there exists $ N_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that \begin{eqnarray}
 \left|\sum\limits_{i=1}^m\sum\limits_{j=1}^n a_i a_j -A \right| \leq \epsilon, \qquad \text{for all } m,n \geq N_0.
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Compare your double sum to the square of the single sum.

Comment: Hint: $a^2-S_n^2=(a+S_n)(a-S_n)\le2a(a-S_n)$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Could you please elaborate a bit

Comment: @AnneBauval what is $S_n$ here? Do you mean to say that the double series converges to $a^2$?

Comment: Compare $\sum_{m,n}a_ma_n$ to $(\sum_ra_r)^2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $S_n:=\sum_{k=1}^na_k$. For all $\epsilon>0$, there exists $N$ such that
$$0\le a-S_N\le\epsilon.$$
We then have
$$\begin{align}\forall m,n\ge N\quad0&\le a^2-\sum\limits_{i=1}^m\sum\limits_{j=1}^na_ia_j\\
&=a^2-S_mS_n\\
&\le a^2-S_N^2\\
&=(a+S_n)(a-S_N)\\
&\le2a(a-S_N)\\
&\le2a\epsilon,
\end{align}$$
which proves that $\sum\limits_{i,j \in \mathbb{N}}a_i a_j$ converges to $a^2$.

Edit, thanks to @Filippo's comment: more generally, given two converging complex sequences $S_n\to a,T_n\to b$, the "doubly indexed sequence" $(S_nT_m)$ converges to $ab$, i.e.
$$\forall\epsilon>0\quad\exists N\quad\forall m,n\ge N\quad|S_nT_m-ab|\le\epsilon,$$
because
$$|S_nT_m-ab|=|(S_n-a)T_m+a(T_m-b)|\le|S_n-a|\sup_{k\in\Bbb N}|T_k|+|a||T_n-b|.$$

Comment: Isn't this simply a special case of the fact that the the product of two convergent sequences converges to the product of the limits?

Answer (score 2):

Let $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^na_i$. Given $S_n$ converges to $a$. Then For an $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $N_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that,
$$
n>N_0\implies|S_n-a|<\varepsilon.
$$
Let $n,m>N_0$, then
$$
|S_n-a|<\varepsilon.
$$
Also,
$$
|S_m-a|<\varepsilon \\
\implies a-\varepsilon<S_m<a+\varepsilon \\
\implies S_m+a<2a+\varepsilon \\
\implies|S_m+a|<2a+\varepsilon.
$$
Multipliying the above two inequalities, we get,
$$
|S_nS_m+a(S_n-S_m)-a^2|<(2a+\varepsilon)\epsilon \\
\implies|S_mS_n-a^2|-a|S_n-S_m|<(2a+\varepsilon)\varepsilon \\
\implies|S_mS_n-a^2| < (2a+\varepsilon)\varepsilon+a|S_n-S_m|.
$$
By cauchy criterion, for an $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $N_1\in\mathbb{N}$, such that
$$
n,m>N_1\implies|S_n-S_m|<\varepsilon.
$$
Let $N=\max(N_0,N_1)$. Then $\forall m,n>N$,
$$
\implies|S_mS_n-a^2|<(2a+\varepsilon)\varepsilon+a|S_n-S_m| \\
\implies|S_mS_n-a^2|<(2a+\varepsilon)\varepsilon+a\varepsilon\\
\implies|S_mS_n-a^2|<(3a+\varepsilon)\varepsilon.
$$
i.,e $S_nS_m=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^na_ia_j$ converges to $a^2$.